# Performance issues for prompt inputs in cognos reports

Tags: performance, cognos

The cognos report takes too much of time when tried to apply a detail filter that takes input from prompt([attrbute_name] = ?input_val?). But if the value is hard coded in the filter ([attrbute_name] = '10101') the report is generated very fast. I am not able to understand the problem with the report.

Can anyone pls suggest my what the error can be?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a custom prompt page?  The field you are filtering on, is it an indexed field?

As a default, when you create a filter on a prompt, Cognos automatically generates a prompt page at run time (assuming you dont have one you defined yourself).  For a character field, the default prompt will be a drop down box.  This drop down will be pre-populated with a list of the first 5000 distinct entries in that field, allowing the user to pick from the list.

If the datasource table/query does not index well when performing a

```
'Select distinct([field you are prompting on]) from [target table]'
```

then loading the values of your prompt can be costly.  On a large table, such as a sales transactions detail table, this could be quite cumbersome.

To fix it, you need to create your own prompt page

```
(Page Explorer->Prompt Pages->Drag 'Page' from the toolbox)
```

Add your own drop down tool, assign it to the prompt value you have already defined, then you can control its behavior.  You can write a custom query to drive your dropdown population, or statically define a few specific options the user can pick from, or use an alternative tool that forces users to type in the value with a 'Text Box Prompt'.